# Вывод сообщения пользователю об ошибке подключения к БД

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet, tomcat

Пишу сервлет с учебной целью на java в Tomcat(пока без jsp), задача - при возникновении ошибки в dao выводить сообщение пользователю. Соединяюсь с дао через листенер. Как это правильно сделать? Как делаю я(неправильно):

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        DAOFactory daoFactory = new MyDaoFactory();
        HttpSession session = event.getSession();
        try {
            Connection con = daoFactory.getConnection();
            session.setAttribute("Dao", daoFactory.getDAO(con));
        }catch (Exception e) {
            session.setAttribute("error", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        HttpSession session = event.getSession();
        ((Dao)session.getAttribute("Dao")).close();
    }
}
```

Сервлет:

```
public class MainServ extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter write = response.getWriter();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        String error = (String)session.getAttribute("error");
        write.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML5>");
        if(error != null){
            write.println("<p>" + "Database access error" +"</p>");
        }
    ...остальной код...
    }
}`
```

Comment: Перенести подключение к БД в самой сервлете, там же и закрытие соединения. Хранить в сессии не нужно. И вообще рекомендую использовать пул соединений к бд.

Comment: Пул соединений это отлично.Если я таким образом буду выводить сообщение пользователю об ошибке, это будет правильным?:                                                             catch (DAOException e) {
            write.println("<p>" + "Database access error" +"</p>");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: Что касательно ошибки. В сервлете, в методе doPost сделать try catch и ловить SQLException. Ну и далее обрабатывать как Вам хочется.

Comment: кто же такое "умное" задание придумал? это не есть правильно.

Comment: такое задание, что поделать

Comment: если я сделаю так в Post пользователю выведется сообщение? catch (DAOException e) {
            write.println("<p>" + "Database access error" +"</p>");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: да. Учтите что write должен быть объявлен перед try catch

Comment: Спасибо большое :)